# Clicking on buttons through a container mask

Tags: html, css

I have a container with some clickable items, and at the bottom of the container, there is a gradient that I'm adding with `.container:after` to create a fade effect. I would still like the items at the bottom to be clickable, but also to be affected by the fade, so putting the fade behind the clickable items won't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/mwjj7hff/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}

.container:after {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, .3) 0%, white 100%);
    bottom: 0;
    content: " ";
    height: 150px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}

li:hover {
   background: #99d; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick, easy solution would be to add [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to the pseudo-element.

In doing so, you can essentially click *through* it:

> [MDN - `pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)
>
> The element is never the target of mouse events; however, mouse events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, mouse events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event capture/bubble phases.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/zx9zdcmk/)

```
.container:after {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, .3) 0%, white 100%);
    bottom: 0;
    content: " ";
    height: 150px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Browser support for `pointer-events` can be [found here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) - currently 87.29%.

Comment: Thanks! If there's a solution that includes IE9/10, that would be better, but this works very well!